# Typescript bindings for static methods that hide a superclass method

Tags: typescript, overloading, static-methods

In Javascript, classes inherit static methods, but subclass methods hide superclass methods with the same name rather than overload them. So you can do this sort of thing:

```
class A {
    static foo(a) { ... }
}
class B extends A {
    static foo(a, b) { ... }
}
```

And you can call A.foo(a) or B.foo(a, b) and it will behave as expected. Unfortunately Typescript doesn't like that, it seems to assume that the same rules apply as for instance methods ie all methods are virtual. So trying to represent the above in a .d.ts file like this:

```
export class A {
    static foo(a: string): void
}
export class B extends A {
    static foo(a: string, b: number): void
}
```

causes an error, because the function signatures are incompatible. I can work around this by duplicating `A`'s declaration of `foo` in `B` as well as `B`'s declaration (.d.ts files don't also require an implementation that's compatible with both), but it's a lie! I'm saying that it's OK to call `B.foo("")`, when in fact that isn't valid and could cause undefined behaviour. This is introducing "type-danger", the opposite of what Typescript is supposed to do. Is there some other way I can represent these methods correctly in Typescript, or at least something like an annotation that will generate a warning in code that tries to call the incorrect version? Is this a bug in Typescript?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug in TypeScript, but a design decision that favors *static inheritance*.

According to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4628#issuecomment-149333638) in [microsoft/TypeScript#4628](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4628), there are apparently two incompatible use cases for the static side of classes.  One group of users wants to see static inheritance as specified by the ES6 specification, which would imply that they should be checked the same way instance inheritance is checked: if you can't substitute the subclass's static property where a superclass's static property is expected, you did something wrong.

The other group of people don't care about substitutability on the static side.  Looks like you're in the latter group... which is too bad for you since TypeScript favors the former.  If you look at that GitHub issue, it looks like they investigated changing this but it sort of fizzled out.  So for now, that's the way it is.

---

So what can you do (other than going to that issue and giving it a )?  If all you care about are *declarations* such as in a .d.ts file, then you can do what the standard library does and describe the interface and static side of the classes separately without using `class`.  (For example, see how [the `Array` class is typed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7a484695ca3452b29b268d037ce1d7dda9d69761/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1392-L1403) with `Array<T>` and `ArrayConstructor`).  Like this:

```
declare namespace MyModule {
  export interface A {
    // instance props/methods
  }
  export interface AConstructor {
    new(): A;
    foo(a: string): void;
  }
  export const A: AConstructor;

  export interface B extends A {
    // new pros/methods
  }
  export interface BConstructor {
    new(): B;
    foo(a: string, b: number): void;
  }
  export const B: BConstructor;
}
```

You can test that this works as expected.

```
MyModule.A.foo("a"); // okay
MyModule.B.foo("a"); // error
```

---

On the other hand, if you care about the actual class definitions with behavior, you could write a class constructor factory function that omits static properties from its typings so that the compiler does not try to enforce static-side substitutability:

```
function NoInheritStatics<A extends any[], R>(
  ctor: new (...a: A) => R
): new (...a: A) => R {
  return ctor;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
class A {
  a: string = "a";
  static foo(a: string) {

  }
}

class B extends NoInheritStatics(A) {
  b: string = "b";
  static foo(a: string, b: string) {

  }
}
```

This behaves as desired:

```
const a = new A();
a.a;
A.foo("a");

const b = new B();
b.a;
b.b;
B.foo("a"); // error!
```

---

Note that neither of these two solutions really change much of anything going on at runtime; there is still static-side inheritance.  All these solutions do is make TypeScript ignore any such inheritance.  If you need to support inheritance of non-overridden static properties (e.g., if `A` has a static `bar()` method and `B` does not, do you want to be able to write `B.bar()`?) it can be done but would be more complicated to write out.  Anyway, hopefully you have some path forward now.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#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-LOwMvcsomTDlsACEwCAA)

Comment: These are good ideas, but I don't think they would solve this particular problem. The classes need to be straightforward to extend ie `class MyClass extends LibClass`. FWIW I'm working on ts-for-gjs which aims to make it easy to use Typescript with gjs. The Javascript is actually wrappers for C libraries which support gobject-introspection. GObject's API fits fairly well with Typescript, but there are a few headaches like this.

Comment: Okay, so then the top part with the link to the relevant GitHub issue constitutes the answer to your question: it’s not a bug in TS, and the requested feature that would address it has not (yet?) been implemented.

Comment: The solution with interfaces does work after all. I had failed to notice that Typescript treats an object whose interface includes `new(...): A` as a class/constructor. Things are further complicated because GObject typically implements constructors as static functions called `new`, so these have to be declared alongside the true JS constructor. This can be done with the syntax `new: (...) => A`.